# Cypress' modifyObstructiveCode works only globally?

Tags: config, cypress

In my tests it appears that setting a config option `modifyObstructiveCode` only works when set globally in `cypress.json`. However, if I set it in a specific test file:

```
Cypress.config('modifyObstructiveCode', false)
```

even though the output of `console.log(Cypress.config())` seems to be as per the setting, it appears to have no effect. Documentation doesn't seem to explictly state that this config option can only be set globally...

Is that the case? Is there a possibily to control this on a file level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was raised in a Cypress issue in 2018

[Add ability to use Cypress.config to set 'modifyObstructiveCode'. #1668](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1668#issuecomment-386160848)

> Yeah for all kinds of reasons this is to be expected. Even though this is a valid configuration value - it affects the proxy layer of Cypress in node - which has nothing to do changing it at runtime in the browser. There are many other options like this and maybe we should throw an error if you try to change them.